# Removing highlight from hover in selected option of split button dropdowns

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap's [split button dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split) for selecting items. It works fine but since the current (selected) option is only for display, while the split dropdown is for showing additional options, I would like to remove the highlight on hover from the current option (left part). Not sure if there's a way besides adding jquery function for that.

```
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could add this CSS:

```
.btn-group .btn.btn-default:not(.dropdown-toggle):hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
    cursor: default;
}
.btn-group .btn.btn-primary:not(.dropdown-toggle):hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
    cursor: default;
}
.btn-group .btn.btn-success:not(.dropdown-toggle):hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #4cae4c;
    cursor: default;
}
```

.. and so on (for the used colorstyles) - maybe with !important.

Comment: Hmm, I like CSS only solutions. Thanks, I was probably overthinking it.

Comment: This works well: .nohover button:first-child:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
    cursor: default;
} and then just add nohover class to btn-group class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.selected:hover{
    background-color: #fff!important;
    background-image: url('none') !important;
    border-color: #fff!important;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu > li > a ").click(function(){
        $(this).parents().eq(1).find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is my normal rout, but I think in this case simple CSS is the better way to go. Thanks.